# How can I call data target after data saved with vue component?

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuejs2, vue-component, custom-data-attribute

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <form>
        ...
        <a href="javascript:" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-cart" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" @click="addToCart">
            <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart
        </a>
        <modal-cart id="modal-cart" :id-product="product.id"></modal-cart>

    </form>
</template>

<script>
    import ModalCart from '../modal/ModalCart.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            ModalCart
        },
        methods: {
            addToCart(event) {
                ...
                this.$store.dispatch('addToCart', data)
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response[0] == true) {
                        //call data-target="#modal-cart"
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```

From the code, if I click add to cart button, it will call `addToCart` method and call `data-target="#modal-cart"` all at once

I want to change it. So if I click add to cart button, it will call `addToCart` method. If the data success saved, then call `data-target="#modal-cart"`

How can I do it?

Comment: Whether there is no one to help?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution here? Solution below does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element using `event.currentTarget` and then access your `data-*` attributes from `dataset` object. So, in your case final mapping should be

`event.currentTarget.dataset.target`

On second thought you should also be able to bind `data-attributes` to a local property and then update it using that, something like

```
<a :data-target="localprop" ...>
....
<script>
  ...
  data: {
    localprop:'someValue'
  },
  ...
  addToCart: function() {
    ...
    this.data.localprop = "new value"
  }
```

This seems like more of `Vue` style of coding, where you avoid querying the dom.